# programming model vs programming paradigm?

Tags: model, paradigms

Can anyone tell me difference between programming model vs programming paradigm ? I have seen these terms many times in literature but I have no idea when to use them can anyone give me an example of these terms usage ? THank you

Answer (score 0):

Paradigm is a set of ideas or concepts.
A model made of the composition of concepts.Model is an example of that.

In programming is the same case programming paradigm is a fundamental style of computer programming.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that?